# Setting the Style of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView class that i am calling in another class

```
 MyPocketTableView * myPocketTableView = [[MyPocketTableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 153, 235, 250) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

However, the init method in the UITableViewClass does not let me do this.

```
@implementation MyPocketTableView

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self = [super initWithStyle:style]

    if (self) {

        //[self setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 153, 235, 250)];
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;

    }
    return self;
}
```

I cannot add style : (UITableViewStyle) style on to the init method definition, nor can i do the `self = [super initWithStyle:style]` because it complains saying

> No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector initWithStyle.

The default init method that was there when the class was created was `- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`. MyPocketTableView is a sub class of UITableView.

```
  @interface MyPocketTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the interface to **`UITableViewController`**, then use `initWithStyle:`.

Also, in doing the following, there is no need to set the UITableView protocol delegates

```
@interface MyPocketTableView : UITableViewController
```

Then you can call:

```
MyPocketTableView * myPocketTableView = [[MyPocketTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

As well as the following:

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style 
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 153, 235, 250)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You can also use the following *(example)* custom method: The key being you are calling:

> **`self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`**

```
- (id) initWithSomeCustomMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 153, 235, 250)];
        self.customMessage = message;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is so basic... just use:  self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];    I don't know why this answer is accepted... it promotes bad practices.

Comment: @BrandonBrodjeski You left a comment yesterday praising my answer and even up voted my answer! Then you turned around and down voted and deleted your comment (which I remind youpraised this answer.) On another note, how is this bad practice? This is how it is supposed to be done. Your answer on the other hand does not even touch on the subject about setting the style of the table view! You should read the Apple documentation more carefully and you should red-read the original question that was asked here.

Comment: I read your answer too quickly and made a mistake is praising it.  It makes absolutely no sense to call [super initWithStyle:] then set the frame when you can just call [super initWithFrame:style:].

Comment: @WrightCS:  Not to mention that you are calling "setFrame" on a UITableViewController, which does not respond to setFrame.  Also, you are naming a subclass of a UITableViewController "MyPocketTableView" which is completely confusing.  this code wouldn't even work...

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to set MyPocketTableView in ViewController as

   ```
   MyPocketTableView * myPocketTableView = [[MyPocketTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
   ```
2. After that, use following code in MyPocketViewcontroller

   ```
   - (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style 
   {
           self = [super initWithStyle:style];
           if (self) {
                   [self setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 153, 235, 250)];
            }
           return self;
   }
   ```
3. dont forget to add UITableView Delegate and Data Source in MyPocketViewController class

Answer (score 1):

You are setting "self" twice.  This will cause "self' to be overwritten.

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
```

In order to maintain the "init chain" you need to call the same "init" function that you are in.  Like this:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle) style {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];
    if(self) {

        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;

    }
    return self;

}
```